# Find duplicate rows for a subset of columns ( not by name but by a percentage threshold)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with more than 100 columns, and I suspect it has duplicate rows, however when I use df.duplicated() (on all columns), it is not returning me any true duplicates, so now i want to see if atleast 80% of the columns in the dataframe have the same values for the rows, Any idea how i can achieve this ?

df.dropna has a threshold parameter where you can give in the number of columns you want as threshold, but df.duplicated() does not have such parameter.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html

Wondering if there is a workaround here ?